# How to use Edit in bootsrap Modal asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using asp.net mvc i want to update data in database using a bootsrap modal
And partial Views.
The broblem is when i click on the link to show the Model it's not working (it shows an empty modal)

this is my Code:

```
     //the Controller Action
         public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Tache tache = db.Taches.Find(id);


            if (tache == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return PartialView("PartialEdit", tache);
        }



   // the index View that contain the link and the modal definition :

         <td>
         <a data-modal='' href='"/Tache/edit/"+@item.TacheId' data-id="@item.TacheId" id="@item.TacheId " title=" edit">Edit </a> |
          @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TacheId })
           </td>

<div id='myModal' class='modal fade'>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// and this  is the Partial View

```
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Nouvelle Tâche</h4>
                </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Tache", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formId" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)





    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TacheId)
                <div class="modal-body">




        //Some  forms in inputs
                    <div class="row">
```

//  Finaly  my javascript :

```
           $(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });
     });

      function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    }
```

I think the problem may came from the link that somthing is missing their !!
but i'm not sure
if someone can  help me that will be great
Think you

Comment: I finaly find the solution ..the problem as i said was in the link  so  i changed   the href"..."  by   href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Tache", new { id = item.TacheId })"......hope this will help someone someday

Comment: Please add your solution as answer so it can be marked accepted to help future visitors!

Comment: yes  i  will  i thought that i have to wait  7 hours before adding it..will try now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have said in my comment the code works perfectly now.

In my Index view I have replaced this:

```
<a data-modal='' href='"/Tache/edit/"+@item.TacheId' data-id="@item.TacheId" id="@item.TacheId " title=" edit">Edit </a>
```

To this:

```
<a data-modal='' href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Tache", new { id = item.TacheId })" data-id="@item.TacheId" id="@item.TacheId " title=" edit">Modifier </a>
```